# changing workspace of jenkins in linux

Tags: linux, jenkins, workspace

I've installed Jenkins on Linux, and I'm new to both. I configured a job with a custom workspace /root/xxxx (directory structure already in place). It gives me the following error:

```
Building in workspace /root/bhanu
java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs: /root/bhanu
at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:847)
```

Another question: when executing *copy* command in *Execute Shell* build step it gives me 'permission denied' error. From the console output the copy command works fine. Here is the error:

```
+ cp /home/user1/victor.war /root/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/
cp: accessing '/root/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/': Permission denied
```

When I try to set permissions in shell script in Jenkins it gives me 'permission denied' error:

```
+ chmod a+rwx /root/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/
chmod: cannot access '/root/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/': Permission denied
```

Comment: This is most likely because jenkins is run as user `jenkins` on most distributions by default and that user has no write access to `/root` - same thing with `chmod`. I suggest installing jenkins from official repository and use the default username. Furthermore, you should use workspace in some _more standard_ location like `/srv/jenkins/workspace`. Run chmod as `root` after creation (e.g  `sudo chmod ...`

Comment: i installed jenkins from root only.can we know from which user we installed jenkins

Comment: when i placed sudo chmod in jenkins it is giving an error that sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
ps aux |grep jenkins
```

to see what user the process has. On Linux, jenkins uses the `JENKINS_USER` variable to define what user it should run as. For a standard Ubuntu package install, the config file in `/etc/default/jenkins` specifies the user in the `JENKINS_USER` variable.

In the same config file, you can also specify the default workspace location using `JENKINS_HOME`. Make sure that is owned by the user you specified in `JENKINS_USER` to have Jenkins access files.

For slave nodes, specify the default workspace on the slave machine in the slave configuration under Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes >  > Configure > Remote FS root. Again, this should have read/write/execute permissions for the `JENKINS_USER` user.